# GUI application to configure wacom draw pad?

Tags: gui, configuration, wacom

I proudly own Wacom Intuos S what is great tool for bedroom-coder / one-man-company like myself. Driver is installed, module is loaded and server is running. Only problem is that I'm unable to find GUI application to configure draw pad. Windows have nice configuration utility, where I can find something similar for Ubuntu linux ? I know there are terminal commands to configure draw pad but for someone who recently switched from Windows, GUI application might be better. I found [one](https://www.linux-apps.com/content/download.php?content=104309&id=1&tan=47836993&PHPSESSID=aa0de810de647036449fe8714da1041f) but it is dead project by now.

Do someone know about such application ?